# Pascal - Enhanced Merge Sort for inversion count wrong output

Tags: arrays, pascal, mergesort, inversion

I've got a homework from school to create a project that would count inversions in an array of integers. I first tried to bruteforce it, but as I expected, I didn't pass the time limit. So after some googling and trying to fully understand mergeSort and how to implement counting of inversions into it, I've made up this code, which unfortunately outputs wrong count, whilst sorting the array correctly:

```
procedure mergeSort(var arr, pomarr : array of longint; start, stop : 
longint; var inv : longint);
var
  mid,i,j,k : longint;
begin
  mid := (start + stop) div 2;
  if (start < mid) then mergeSort(arr,pomarr,start,mid,inv);
  if (mid+1 < stop) then mergeSort(arr,pomarr,mid+1,stop,inv);

  i := start;
  k := start;

  while (i<= mid) and (j <= stop) do begin
    if (arr[i] < arr[j]) then begin
      pomarr[k] := arr[i];
      i += 1;
    end
    else begin
      pomarr[k] := arr[j];
      inv += mid - i;
      j += 1;
    end;
    k += 1;
  end;
  while (i <= mid) do begin
    pomarr[k] := arr[i];
    i += 1;
    k += 1;
  end;
  while (j <= stop) do begin
    pomarr[k] := arr[j];
    j += 1;
    k += 1;
  end;

  for k := start to stop do begin
    arr[k] := pomarr[k];
  end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance for all your help. I know it's just some stupid mistake in a declaration, but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?  SO is not an online debugging service.

Comment: According to SO help, either homework and debugging questions aren't off limits. I do realize this site isn't meant for fixing my inattentiveness, but I've done all I could think of and now I'm stuck at this point. I can't strip anymore of the code and the sorting itself is working, so there's just some problem I can't wrap my head around. My question is where is the issue with my code.

Comment: Does your Pascal compiler not have a debugger?  Debugging is the main thing you are meant to learn from exercises like this.

Comment: I'm running lazarus and I tried stripping parts of the code. Also to run it line by line, but as far as I'm concerned, everything works just as intendeed, expect the count variable. I've tried to sketch the array on a paper but I couldn't think of any flaw in the declaration, except that it should be mid - i + 1, but neither that outputs the correct numbers.

Comment: For a problem like this, if you can't identify the error by watching the variables under the debugger, the next thing to consider is logging:  write a routine that records the values of the variables on each loop iteration, then print it out and study it carefully.  Usually this results in a "doh!" moment.

Comment: I tried. I've set up a new function that wrote out the operated part of arr as well as pomarr. However with some help of my tutor, I managed to fix the problem, and it wasn't the fault of declarations actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I somewhat managed to fix my problem. I asked my teacher what might cause this issue, and he told me, that there is actually a difference between declaring a type of variable in the head of the program and declaring it in the body. Afterwards I fixed my program by creating an array type:

```
type
  numlist = array[1..250000] of longint;
```

and declared my used arrays in function and everywhere else via this type. And it actually worked.

From what I could collect, if you declare an array without using the type, iteration actually starts from 0, not from 1 as usual. I honestly have no idea how these two facts are related, but it fixed my problem and now it runs as intended.

If anybody knows what causes this iteration shift, please let me know. I'm actually even more confused than I was before.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Declaring an array using array bounds like 1 and 250000 is what you might call a "traditional Pascal declaration" which has its origins in Pascal having been designed as a teaching language.  It was intended I suppose to make the point that you could choose the bounds to suit your problem.  These days, it's more "fashionable" to declare arrays with zero as the lower bound, and FPC/Lazarus and Delphi have array support routines like `SetLength` which allow you to set the array size at run-time, but at the cost that the array you get is always zero-based.

Comment: Btw, there is a very good article here:http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html about array declarations in Delphi, which is applicable to FPC/Lazarus too.